# jquery on click event not working on list items within unordered list

Tags: jquery

I have the following list withing an unordered list with id #sortable1, what I want to achieve is whenever a li element is clicked withing < ul id="sortable2"> an onclick event should happen and alert the id from the li element that was clicked. I have one element also within the unordered list that should not be clickable with the class="emptyMessage"

I got stuck and dont know how to proceed

So far I have

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable ui-sortable">
<li class="ui-state-default" id="1">Name1</li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id="2">Name2</li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id="3">Name3</li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id="4">Name4</li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id="5">Name5</li>
<li style="display: list-item;" class="emptyMessage">No more contacts available</li></ul>
```

My JQUERY code

```
$("#sortable1 li").click(function() {
          alert('Clicked list.'+$(this).value);
         });
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$("#sortable1 li").not('.emptyMessage').click(function() {
       alert('Clicked list. ' + this.id);
});
```

Demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/gztRq/2/

Comment: Yeah, `.text()` is a better choice here.

Comment: But he did asked for the id in the question :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#sortable1 > li.ui-state-default").click(function() {
    alert("Clicked list " + $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntax error in your JavaScript. It should be:

```
$("#sortable1 li").click(function() {
    alert("Clicked list." + $(this).value);
});
```

Also, I think you mean `$(this).html()`, not `$(this).value` - `<li>`s don't have a value (and it would be `.val()` on a jQuery object).

[Here's a working version](http://jsfiddle.net/MWpmD/).

Comment: @jAndy - yeah, I just spotted that :)

Comment: It still does not exclude `.emptyMessage`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe wrong selector? Here's my code (works just fine):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MooExample</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#sortable1 > li").click(function() {
                    alert($(this).html());
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable ui-sortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default" id="1">Name1</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default" id="2">Name2</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default" id="3">Name3</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default" id="4">Name4</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default" id="5">Name5</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

**UPD:** i'm sorry, i think `<li>` items have no *val()* property =)

Answer (score 0):

use this to be more specific while selecting

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul#sortable1 li").click(function() {
    alert("Clicked list." + $(this).text());
});
});
```